# Sending user screen views information through Google Analytics v4

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

When I visit a screen in my application, I am notified that the screen is being viewed. Then when I change to a different screen, I do not receive any notification and after a while, Google Analytics says that nobody is viewing the application, when the application is still open on my android device.

Seems as if I am notified when the user views one screen, but not if the user views any subsequent screens.

Any help would be much appreciated.

My code is along the following lines:

I set up everything according to: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Also, for each activity (below is for AboutActivity), I added the following:

AboutActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  // Get tracker.
  Tracker t = ((MyApplication) AboutActivity.this.getApplication()).getTracker(
  TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

  // Set screen name.
  // Where path is a String representing the screen name.
  t.setScreenName("AboutActivity");

  // Send a screen view.
  t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
}
```